# How to show $\int_0^1 x^{-x} \mathrm dx = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty n^{-n}$.

Tags: real-analysis

> I need to show that $$\int_0^1 x^{-x} \mathrm  dx = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty n^{-n}$$

I tried using that $x^{-x} = e^{-x\ln(x)}$, but I don't know what to do about when $x = 0$ since the equality does not hold. I also tried using the power series expansion of $e^x$, but I don't really know where to go from there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is known as a special case of [Sophomore's Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream).

Comment: Relevant video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Fpu9Ylb9_E

Comment: But $x=0$ is only one point. A point has measure zero, and so does not affect the integration.